# In objective-c is it always wrong to repeat a bunch of code or are there occasions where it doesn't matter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Take a look at my `UICollectionView` dataSource method below. In the if statement I repeat myself. I'm basically setting properties in two different custom `UICollectionViewCell's`. They have the exact same properties and the only differences between these cells are visual differences.

I was thinking of ways to put the repeated code into another method and pass in the cell and call the method from within the cellForItemAtIndexPath method but remembered they are different classes.

**Code:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

        NSLog(@"collectionview 1 loaded");

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        VAGGarmentCell *cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        VAGGarmentCell2 *cell2 = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout]) {
        [[cell activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];

        [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell;

    } else if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout2]) {
        [[cell2 activityIndicator] startAnimating];

        PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        [[cell2 imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
        [[cell2 imageView] loadInBackground];

        [[cell2 activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

        [[cell2 title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell2 price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
        return cell2;
    }

     return 0;

    //_addToFavouritesButton = [cell addFavouriteButton];

    [_addToFavouritesButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(addToFavouritesButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a big deal?
2. What would you do in this situation?

I decided to use 2 separate cells instead of using one and changing constraints of the properties because it became really messy.

I'd appreciate any advice or ideas or just your opinion.

Regards.

Comment: Repeating code that doesn't have to be repeated should always be avoided when practical to do so. It looks like the only difference in your example is `cell` vs `cell2`... you could set a new local based on your conditional, to one of those values, and then have just a single block of code applying its methods. This makes things much more readable and less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to have the two cell variables. The only conditional part of this function is which object you're operating on, so you can just conditionally assign to one variable.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    NSLog(@"collectionview 1 loaded");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    VAGGarmentCell *cell = nil;

    if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout]) {
        cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if ([[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] isEqual: _flowLayout2]) {
        cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    [[cell activityIndicator] startAnimating];

    PFFile *userImageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
    [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
    [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];

    [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

    [[cell title] setText:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@ GBP", [object valueForKey:@"price"]]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: As you've lost `VAGGarmentCell2` the OP should becareful if they add a `VAGGarmentCell2` specific method and want to call it - put it in the `if` statement as if `CellIdentifier2` has been registered against the `VAGGarmentCell2` class (I assume it has), then `cell` won't be an instance of `VAGGarmentCell` and you'll have no compiler warnings as `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns a object of type `id`. Just something to bear in mind...!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing "`VAGGarmentCell`" and "`VAGGarmentCell2`" are both descended from some *base* class.  E.G. "`BaseGarmentCell`", which eventually descends from "`UITableViewCell`".

Why not put these lines:

```
    [[cell imageView] setFile: userImageFile];
    [[cell imageView] loadInBackground];

    [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];
```

into a separate method that lives in your "`BaseGarmentCell`" .m file, that you can call when you populate your cell via "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`".

And to answer your specific questions:

1) is this a big deal?  No... it just improves the readability of your code and makes things a lot more simple.

2) What would I do in this situation?  Just what I put above.  :-)